# Uninstall Lexmark s300 from XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, lexmark-printer

I had a Lexmark S300 Wireless printer.  It has not worked for years!!  I recently replaced it with a HP6830.

The 6830 works fine, great printer, wireless.  The only problem is it will not scan from the XP computer.  When scan is initiated it say HP printer not found.  This only happens when trying to scan.

I have been told this is because Lexmark install writes to the registry and XP only allows one printer.

Even after completely unistalling the Lexmark folders are still in the registery.  So is there any way to fix this?

There are 2 registry files for Lexmark.  One includes Scan and Twain. Can I simply delete those??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove those. Also any other entries that remained so.
But it's better that you use a registry cleaner / uninstall cleaner since certainly there will be more trash-things that remained around.

As for the HP, try an older version of the software...and try to use the scan from the HP central program that installs with the driver. It's called HP scan. That should detect your scanner-side correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the HP 6830 is one of their newest printers.  There is no "older software"   We are still on the original.

I did run a registry clean program, no help.  In the end, I just hard deleted the Lexmark files from the registry.

It seems one of the problems is that I was never able to successfully install XP SP3.  It will never work with out SP3.

After finally updating to SP3 I find I can not update .NET Framework as the newer versions do not work with XP. So it seems scanning from this computer is probably never going to work.  The great tech guys at HP mught come up with a work round, but I think what I really need is a upgrade.  :)